# first timer.. java exception

Tags: java, apache-pig

I am new into java world.. But basically I am trying to write a user-defined-function in pig-latin.

The following is the relevant code.

```
public class time extends EvalFunc<String>{

public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

    if ((input == null) || (input.size() == 0))
        return null;
    try{
        String time = (String) input.get(0) ;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.000");
        Date date = df.parse(time);
        String timeOfDay = getTimeOfDay(date);
        return timeOfDay;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

So basically input is a tuple... I do a check whether the tuple is empty or not..
And then get convert that date string to time object.. and then parse the time part.. 
and then the function

```
  getTimeOfDay(date) returns a string... like breakfast, lunch dinner.. or empty string depending on the time hours..
```

Now the issue is that my eclipse says and error (red line)  in

```
 Date date = df.parse(time);
 String timeOfDay = getTimeOfDay(date);
```

says

```
 Unhandled exception type ParseException
```

But no matter what I try (gives me 3 options.. add catch clause to surrounding try, add exception to existing catch block and surround with try/catch..), the error shifts.. but is always tehre.

And i am not even sure that I can change the structure of program..(the method declaration etc)..

How do I resolve this.

```
  A quick guide on udf http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual
```

If you know pig.. or knows an easy method.. then basically what i am trying to do is .. given an input string of type "time,id,amount" check at what time of the day the transaction was made?

THanks

Comment: Did you try adding `try-catch` to handle `ParseException`?

Comment: What is the value you are getting into String time ? Is it in format hh:mm:ss.000?

Comment: @RohitJain Yes i did.. but then the error shifts to public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException (the method must return tyype string??

Comment: (Oh wait, you already know this) If you point to the red squiggly line showing the error, Eclipse will suggest you quick fixes. Just click on the most appropriate quick fix and Eclipse will automatically fix it for you. It's like magic!

Comment: You can declare your `timeOfDay;` outside the try-catch block. And return it after the try-catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your exec method is already declared to throw IOException, you do not need to catch it and throw it as the `throws` declaration will automatically do that.
- As for ParseException you have to decide how to handle it.
- Also a bracket was missing =)

So your code should be:

```
public class time extends EvalFunc<String>{

public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

    if ((input == null) || (input.size() == 0))
        return null;
    try{
        String time = (String) input.get(0) ;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.000");
        Date date = df.parse(time);
        String timeOfDay = getTimeOfDay(date);
        return timeOfDay;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //how will I handle when df.parse(time) fails and throws ParseException?
        //maybe:
        return null;
    }
  } //exec

} //class
```